# Sidebar inside page conten

Tags: shortcode, widgets, custom-content

I have WordPress page's or pages' layout like this:
[image]

I'm wondering what would be the best way to handle this.

1. I was thinking about adding shortcode inside column, that would export widget area:

```
function sidebar_area() {
    $output = '<div>' . dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) . '</div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'sidebar_area', 'sidebar_area' );
```

This code displays widgets from the area, but also gives me errors, and I cannot find a proper way to do it (if it's even possible).

2. I could add in page template content from another page (pased on custom property, which would be page slug. It will probably work, but it won't be most proper way of doint this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you include the errors in your question? Without the errors there's no way to know what to do. Also you're appending `dynamic_sidebar` to a string, but that function does not return strings, it outputs them directly, breaking the shortcode. You need at an absolute minimum output buffers there, much in the same way that writing `echo "test";` inside a shortcode breaks things